# Does Spark collect_list send data to the driver?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

With this snippet in pyspark:

```
 df.groupBy('id').agg(collect_list('feature'))
```

I keep running out of memory on the driver. 
So, I'm assuming collection process takes place on the driver. 
If this is correct, is a UDAF implemented in Scala my only option to avoid this OOM?

Thanks

Comment: hey, i'm getting similar errors. did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Not really. If I remember it right, simply restarting the cluster fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, the "collect" is a little misleading here.